# How to extract Ageing report using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to prepare an ageing report using SQL to identify how much payment has been due for
a.  90-120 days
b.  60-90 days
c.  30-60 days
d.  0-30 days

This should be calculated as on 6th April 2016.

Output should be like - 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d83f4/1

Comment: 1) I think you mistook SO for a free coding service. If you would like some proper answer, then follow the linked guidance how to ask a good sql related question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query 2) You should also confirm which rdbms product you use: MySQL or sql server.

Comment: I apologize as I put it in same way as asked in a written test of my interview. I use SQL server. Also I shared this solution but not sure if its correct, 
`code` select (case when t.DaysAgo between 0 and 30 then '0-30'
             when t.DaysAgo between 31 and 60 then '31-60'
             else '0'
        end

Answer (score 0):

Good question. 
You would need to add a column or two in order for you to get this.

1. You'll need to have a calculated column letting you know the difference in days from today's date to the date of service/sale.
2. One more column is needed here, and that will "bucket" the record as per your pre-assigned buckets.
3. You can have a case statement do the work for each of these columns.

If you post some queries showing some work along these lines, we, at SO can help you along to correct your calculation.